# Ionic 2: How to fix usage of moment.js errors

Tags: typescript, npm, momentjs, ionic2, typescript-typings

Since updating to RC.0, I'm getting the following build error to do with moment.js (which I have installed via npm):

```
[13:44:16]  Error: Cannot call a namespace ('moment')
```

I have tried referencing moment in two ways:

- `import * as moment from 'moment';`
- `import moment from 'moment'`

The error is the same.

**Q) What am I doing wrong? This was working before RC.0**

Comment: I'm having the same problem, looks like it's a known issue - https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/68

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `import * as Moment from 'moment';` I was getting the error: Cannot call a namespace ('Moment').

Changing it to `import Moment from 'moment';` resolved the issue.

Comment: import Moment from 'moment' is not accepted by typescript compiler (at least 2.1.6)

Answer (score 3):

Have you doubled checked in all your project files that you have made the change, as it sounds like you might have just missed one?

Try changing the moment-node.d.ts from

export = moment;
to
export default moment;

this will expose any missing files. (Then change it back.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add moment to the types in the tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "moment" <====== THIS
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Also, need to add the reference to moment in commonjs in @ionic's rollup.config.js

```
var ngTemplate = require('../dist/plugins/ng-template').ngTemplate;
var nodeResolve = require('rollup-plugin-node-resolve');
var commonjs = require('rollup-plugin-commonjs');

// https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/JavaScript-API

var rollupConfig = {

  useStrict: false,

  /**
   * entry: The bundle's starting point. This file will
   * be included, along with the minimum necessary code
   * from its dependencies
   */
  entry: './.tmp/app/main.dev.js',

  /**
   * sourceMap: If true, a separate sourcemap file will
   * be created.
   */
  sourceMap: true,

  /**
   * format: The format of the generated bundle
   */
  format: 'iife',

  /**
   * dest: the output filename for the bundle in the buildDir
   */
  dest: 'main.js',

  /**
   * plugins: Array of plugin objects, or a single plugin object.
   * See https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Plugins for more info.
   */
  plugins: [
    ngTemplate(),
    commonjs({
        include: [
        'node_modules/moment/**'
        ]
    }),
    nodeResolve({
      module: true,
      jsnext: true,
      main: true,
      browser: true,
      extensions: ['.js']
    })
  ]

};  

if (process.env.IONIC_ENV == 'prod') {
  // production mode
  rollupConfig.entry = '.tmp/app/main.prod.js';
  rollupConfig.sourceMap = false;
}

module.exports = rollupConfig;
```

Comment: This also works for firebase and lodash and I imagine other 3rd party frameworks.

Comment: It does not work: I still have the message: Cannot call a namespace ('moment')

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to make work moment with typescript (at 2.1.6) and rollup (0.41.4).

1. To import moment, keep the standard way:

   `import * as moment from 'moment';`

`import moment from 'moment';` is non-standard for a package without a default export, it will result an error at runtime: `moment_1.default is not a function`

2. In typescript use moment with by casting moment as any, and call the `default` function:

   ```
   var momentFunc = (moment as any).default ? (moment as any).default : moment;
   var newFormat = momentFunc(value).format( format );
   ```

`moment(value).format(format)` will result an error at rollup tree shaking: `Cannot call a namespace ('moment')`